# Adding Videos as post-thumbnails (no stills, just the player in a smaller size)

Tags: post-thumbnails, excerpt, videos, video-player

I’m using Excerpts with post-thumbnails on my startsite. Adding Images is working pretty fine. But how can I embed a video from vimeo or youtube as a post-thumbnail? Just the video in a smaller size, not a screenshot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a plugin which adds a meta box in admin, where you can add a link to a youtube/vimeo video. The plugin should then save the url as meta data for that article when the article is saved.

When listing the articles (or viewing a single one), check if the meta data value is set. If it is, then output the corresponding embed code instead of the post-thumbnail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I’ve found a plugin called Featured Video (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-video/). This was okay for now. And it shows the Difficulties: you need to change the embed-code of the video to resize the player for the »post-Thumbnail«. Unfortunately the plugin only supports vimeo and youtube.

So, for Soundcloud I had to built another Meta-Box and did it with _Advanced Custom Fields_. I’ve created just a new wysiwyg-editor and put a variable into the container for the post-thumbnail.